# How do I access T in an Option<T> without causing a move?

Tags: rust

I'm working on an insert function in a binary search tree implementation. Here's my code:

```
pub struct Node {
    data: i32,
    left: Option<Box<Node>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node>>
}

fn insert_at_root(mut root_node: Node, new_node: Node) -> Node { //not reference because root_node will be mutated
    if root_node.data > new_node.data { // value less than root
        if let Some(left) = root_node.left {
            insert_node(*left, new_node); // *left is a way to downcast box, i.e. *left = T from Box<T>
        }
        else {
            root_node.set_left(Some(Box::new(new_node)));
        }
    }
    else if root_node.data < new_node.data {
        if let Some(right) = root_node.right {
            insert_node(*right, new_node);
        }
        else {
            root_node.set_right(Some(Box::new(new_node)));
        }
    }
    root_node
}

fn insert_node(mut exist_node: Node, new_node: Node) -> () {
    if exist_node.data > new_node.data {
        if let Some(left) = exist_node.left {
            insert_node(*left, new_node);
        }
        else {
            exist_node.set_left(Some(Box::new(new_node)));
        }
    }
    else if exist_node.data < new_node.data {
        if let Some(right) = exist_node.right {
            insert_node(*right, new_node);
        }
        else {
            exist_node.set_right(Some(Box::new(new_node)));
        }
    }
}
```

I have two insert functions so I can preserve the variable with the root node when I call insert_at_node.

My current problem is the line `if let Some(left) = root_node.left {` (and the line `if let Some(right) = root_node.right {`) in the `insert_at_root` function which apparently causes a move. As a result, I can't return `root_node` at the end of `insert_at_node`:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `root_node`
  --> src/lib.rs:34:5
   |
19 |         if let Some(left) = root_node.left {
   |                     ---- value moved here
...
34 |     root_node
   |     ^^^^^^^^^ value used here after partial move
   |
   = note: move occurs because value has type `std::boxed::Box<Node>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to previous error
```

The purpose of those lines is to check if the `left` (or `right`) child node is not `None`, basically `root_node.left != None`.
Is there any way to achieve this without causing a move? Maybe something with an `!=` or `==` sign.

Comment: `Option` has a `.is_some()` – But your problem is not that you're testing wither this is `Some` or `None` but that you bind the content of the `Option` to `left`/`right` to modify it afterwards.

Comment: Additional note: you commented the first function with "not reference because root_node will be mutated", but you do mutate the passed node in the second function as well. So indeed you could just use the second function and always pass a reference. That would remove a lot of duplicated code.

Comment: And there is no need to add a `-> ()` if the function does not return anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're problem is not that you test whether `left`/`right` is `Some` or `None`. BTW that could be done with the tests `.is_some()` and `.is_none()`.

The problem you have is that you bind the variable `left` to the `Node` that is in the `Option`. By that you move the ownership of the content of the `Option` to the `left` variable.

In general if you don't want to move the ownership, you have to work with references. When ever the variable is inside an `Option` and you need to look inside it as a reference, you have to convert the type of it from `Option<T>` to `Option<&T>`. By than when you look inside the option, it's just a reference, and therefor doesn't move the ownership.

There are two functions available on `Option` that do this conversion: `.as_ref()` to convert to an immutable reference, and `.as_mut()` that converts to a mutable reference. Because you want to modify the content of `left` you need a mutable reference, so `.as_mut()` as what you want.

By using `.as_mut()` the `left` you get is a reference instead of the variable itself, so no ownership was transferred.

The next problem you get is that you cannot pass a reference into `insert_node` because the type signature of this function requires to get the variable instead of a reference. By that it would required that you pass the ownership inside this helper function, so it also wouldn't work. So we convert the signature of `insert_node` to take `&mut Box<Node>` instead of `Node`. So again we only take a reference and not the ownership.

```rust
pub fn insert_at_root(mut root_node: Node, new_node: Node) -> Node {
    //not reference because root_node will be mutated
    if root_node.data > new_node.data {
        // value less than root
        if let Some(left) = root_node.left.as_mut() {
            insert_node(&mut *left, new_node);
        } else {
            root_node.set_left(Some(Box::new(new_node)));
        }
    } else if root_node.data < new_node.data {
        if let Some(right) = root_node.right.as_mut() {
            insert_node(&mut *right, new_node);
        } else {
            root_node.set_right(Some(Box::new(new_node)));
        }
    }
    root_node
}

pub fn insert_node(exist_node: &mut Box<Node>, new_node: Node) -> () {
    if exist_node.data > new_node.data {
        if let Some(left) = exist_node.left.as_mut() {
            insert_node(&mut *left, new_node);
        } else {
            exist_node.set_left(Some(Box::new(new_node)));
        }
    } else if exist_node.data < new_node.data {
        if let Some(right) = exist_node.right.as_mut() {
            insert_node(&mut *right, new_node);
        } else {
            exist_node.set_right(Some(Box::new(new_node)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. Quick related follow-up, I have declared a variable like so `let mut root = Box::new(Node {data: 13, ..Default::default() });`. why do I have to call the insert function like `insert_node(&mut root, new_node)` instead of just `insert_node(&root, new_node)`. I assume the `mut` in my root declaration means that the variable is mutable whenever it's being used.